# What's the word for when a person states something as a fact when it is untrue? Not a lie

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm thinking of a specific author who propagates misinformation as fact. There's a word for this, I think it starts with an 'e', but I can't quite remember it and it is on the tip of my tongue. Any information will help. Thanks!

Also, the answer is not "a lie" or a "deception" or anything along those lines, because the person spreading the (mis)information believes it to be true. It's describing the act of promoting this information.

Comment: Are you thinking of "propoganda"?

Comment: I believe the term is politician.

Comment: The [technical philosophical term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Bullshit) is ***Bullshit***.

Comment: @John, I read that book and I *love* it.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing this as not a lie. Repeating an untruth or telling it the first time, it's still a lie.

Comment: Lying requires knowledge that the fact is untrue. Otherwise, the statement is just incorrect.

Comment: @Oldcat: OK, then you're saying the intention and knowledge of what one is saying is important. So if the person believes it is true but has no idea that what they are saying is in fact not true, Then they are definitely not lying. But I don't know what to call it. They're not bullshitting, they're not waffling or trying to deceive.So Meaghan, which scenario are you thinking of?

Comment: @Mitch - I'm referring to the first situation, wherein the person believes they are what they are stating is actually true, but it isn't (think Graham Hancock). The word I'm thinking of refers to the act of doing this. When a person uses their position as a platform to promote their agenda. I remember my coworker used the word the other day, but she isn't in the office yet, so I cannot ask her. I'll update this whenever I get the answer from her. It has been driving me crazy all day.

Comment: [Confabulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confabulation)? - Confabulation is distinguished from lying as there is no intent to deceive and the person is unaware the information is false.

Comment: Is the author a creationist by any chance?

Comment: @ermanen This should be an answer, because it's a good word to describe this.

Answer (score 5):

Isaac Asimov once said to someone about this distinction: "I will allow you to question the **accuracy** of my statement but never its **veracity**"

If a statement lacks veracity the speaker is lying. It it is just wrong, then he is inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

**[Equivocate](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivocate)**

*(verb)* Use ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing oneself.

Comment: Not quite, but closer than anyone else. The act I'm thinking of requires the speaker to have no idea that what they are stating is incorrect, so in this case, they wouldn't have anything to conceal, as they believe what they are stating to be fact.

Comment: @Meaghan In that case I believe the word you are looking for might be **Erroneous**

Comment: @Meaghan I'd say that the person was *ignorant*, in the sense that he ignores the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make all of these start with an 'e' without misspelling them, but perhaps they'll jog your memory.

> Propagandist  (with credit to @Dan Bron)
>
> Misinformer

A synonym of propagandist is evangelist.  Depending on the context, demagogue might apply.

Comment: Is there an extra 'n' in propagandist?

Comment: Thanks @Enigmadan, I should have said I couldn't respond without misspelling :)

Answer (score 1):

**nescience**

> (n) Absence of knowledge or awareness; ignorance.

[Nescient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nescient) (adj) is synonymous with misinformed and ignorant, inasmuch as the person either deliberately or unwittingly  expounds beliefs that are clearly false

**self-deceiving**

> allowing oneself to believe that a false or unvalidated feeling, idea, or situation is true.

Wikipedia says on *[self-deception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deception)*

> Self-deception is a process of denying or rationalizing away the
>   relevance, significance, or importance of opposing evidence and
>   logical argument. *Self-deception involves convincing oneself of a
>   truth (or lack of truth) so that one does not reveal any
>   self-knowledge of the deception*

Comment: @WS2 Fine, I wasn't aware I was in trouble. I'd already gone to bed.

Comment: @WS2 you might want to delete your comment now, it's pretty much obsolete. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about "[fudge](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=fudge%20meaning&gbv=2&oq=fudge%20meaning&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0j0i7i30l3j0j0i7i30l2j0i20j0i7i30l2.1047.8218.0.9390.7.7.0.0.0.0.250.1109.0j4j2.6.0.msedrc...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..1.6.1109.6LVMfMFbmG0)"... (verb)

- present or deal with (something) in a vague or inadequate way, especially so as to conceal the truth or mislead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps thinking of an **exaggerator, embellisher** or **embroiderer?**

Generally speaking, the first-named *overstates* the facts, the second makes them seem *better than they are,* and the third *entirely invents* certain aspects of the information they are propagating.

Answer (score 0):

Mistaken

> : to understand (something or someone) incorrectly
>   : to make a wrong judgment about (something)
>   : to identify (someone or something) incorrectly

Full Definition of MISTAKE

> *transitive verb*
>   1:  to blunder in the choice of 
>   2a:  to misunderstand the meaning or intention of :misinterpret 
>   2b:  to make a wrong judgment of the character or ability of
>   3:  to identify wrongly :confuse with another

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistaken

Comment: Or “misinformed”,  or perhaps “misguided”.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question seems to regard when somebody does something, I would suppose that you want a verb, so my guess is that your forgotten word is Err, under this definition of the word from the American Dictionary of the English Language (A.D.E.L.) by Noah Webster:

> 3. To mistake; to commit error; to do wrong from ignorance or inattention. Men err in judgment from ignorance, from want of attention to facts, or from previous bias of mind.

Committing error should be cross referenced with the **error** entry, which starts with the following passage and more directly asserts the criterion of belief in the claim being made:

> A wandering or deviation from the truth; a mistake in judgment, by which men assent to or believe what is not true. error may be voluntary, or involuntary. Voluntary, when men neglect or pervert the proper means to inform the mind; involuntary, when the means of judging correctly are not in their power.

And similarly A.D.E.L. shows an false statement can be described with the adjective erroneous:

> 4. Wrong; false; mistaken; not conformable to truth; erring from truth or justice; as an erroneous opinion or judgment.

It also shows that all three of these words are cognate, as they derive from the latin Erro.

The word is particularly common in a few phrases, such as "To err is human" or "err on the side of caution", howevter in these cases it more broadly means to make any sort of mistake, rather than making false claims specifically.

Nevertheless, it can be specifically applied to false claims as well and such usage is extensively demonstrated in* A Relation of the Conference Between William Laud, Late Lord Arc-Bishop of Canturbury and Mr. Fisher the Jesuit By the Command of King James of Ever Blessed Memory with An Answer to Such Exceptions as A.C. Takes  Against it* (fourth edition revised 1685)* which includes many uses of the word. This source is especially useful since I presume, at least for the  mostpart, the correspondents hold the holiest of men in the Church of Christ as honest people, working hard to determine the most accurate interpretation of  holy scripture, and the nature of the question considers the possibility that their consensus is beyond fault.

I have some difficulty selecting a specific passage for the sake of inclusion, but I think this one [from what seems to be page 146](https://books.google.com/books?id=2DuWyZuRKB0C&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false) is useful.

> B. Whether a General Council may err or not is  a question of great consequence in the Church of Christ. To say it cannot err, leaves the church not only without remedy against an error once determined, but also without sense that it may need a remedy, and so without care to seek it; which is the misery of the Church of Rome at this day. To say it can err, seems to expose the Members of the Church to an uncertainty, and wavering in the faith; to make unquiet spirits, not only to disrespect former Councils of the Church, but also to slight and contemn whatever it may now determine: Into which error some Opposers of the Church of Rome have fallen. And upon your question, wherein are we nearer to unity, if a Council may err?  As if Grounds of Faith may vary at the Racket, and be caft of each fide, as a cunning Hand might lay them.

To briefly address the concerns of people who  may have doubt that this usage remains contemporary, I shall also provide a definition written in The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary 5th Edition (©2002)

> 4. Make a wrong judgement; form a wrong opinion; make a mistake, blunder; (of a statement) be incorrect. M.E.

Unlike the first and fifth definitions, this meaning was not marked with the dagger of obsolescence.

Answer (score -1):

**naieve**

```
adjective
(of a person or action) showing a lack of experience, wisdom, or judgment.
"the rather naive young man had been totally misled"
(of a person) natural and unaffected; innocent.
"Andy had a sweet, naive look when he smiled"

synonyms:   innocent, unsophisticated, artless, ingenuous, inexperienced, guileless, unworldly, trusting; More
```